# How can I make /tmp executable?

Tags: upgrade, tmp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10. When I clicked in the Update Manager Upgrade a message box apeared:

> Cannot run the upgrade. This usually is caused by a system where /tmp is mounted noexec. Please remount without noexec and run the upgrade again.

I tried to make `/tmp` executable in Terminal with the following command:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp /var/tmp
```

I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I got the following message from Terminal:

```
mount: only root can do that
```

What should I do now to make `/tmp` executable and upgrade the OS?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you include the output of `cat /proc/mounts` in your question? To be sure about the configuration on your system.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to have root privileges. For this, put `sudo` in front of the command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

When you are asked for a password, just enter your usual user password.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. Instead I get a : "mount: /tmp not mounted or bad option" error

Comment: It does not work for me either.

Answer (score 5):

It shows that your `/tmp`  is mounted as noexec, so try to mount it with `exec` option in order to make your upgrade work.

```
exec / noexec - Permit/Prevent the execution of binaries from the filesystem.
```

Open the  `/etc/fstab` file as root, for example run

```
sudoedit /etc/fstab
```

Change the below line (`/tmp` entry on fstab for mine looks like this) from

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777,nosuid,size=512M,noexec 0 0
```

to

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777,nosuid,size=512M,exec 0 0
```

Or, if your line looks different, just remove and replace `noexec` in the fourth column with `exec`.

Save that file and then restart your system. Now try to upgrade again.

Answer (score 4):

Would you try this command? In my case, this worked.

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o exec tmpfs /tmp
```

and then, check if it worked.

```
mount
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Privileges and permissions in linux can be confusing. I recommend reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) before you start using sudo. Once you understand the difference between root, sudo, and normal user, you'll have a much better grasp of why this error happened (and *nix in general). See also the man pages for chown and chmod.

Answer (score -1):

Other answers tell you how to make `/tmp` executable temporarily. To persist this setting:

1. Edit `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount` (`sudo systemctl edit tmp.mount --full`).
2. Find the line with mount options (like `Options=mode=1777,relatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec`).
3. Delete the `noexec` option.

From now on, your `/tmp` will be executable even after restarts!

Comment: To the downvoters: I know about potential security implications. `/tmp` was made `noexec` for some reasons, probably. I have no intentions to argue with that. I'm just answering the question. If one already decided to make it executable, who we are to judge. And here is a [link to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061328/171572) is where I found the mention of `tmp.mount` systemd unit.

Comment: I would be interested to know the context of this - my (Lubuntu 20.04) system has no file `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount` (and certainly the person asking this question before the adoption of systemd by Ubuntu wouldn't either, but there's nothing this site needs more than up-to-date answers, so that isn't a criticism), `/tmp` isn't mentioned in `mount` and so does not appear to have its own mount options. What are you running?

Comment: @Zanna, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I just realized I put two identical answers for this question. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: thanks... interesting... that wasn't a mistake by you - when you post *the exact same answer* to two different questions, we get a flag (the other question did not have any answers that gave a temporary solution - it's good read the stuff on the page and adjust if re-posting!) - I merged the two questions (which moves answers from one to the other) as they were duplicates, the other one had less detail, and Avinash's answer seemed worth moving over.