# Make all new .sh file executable

Tags: bash, scripts, chmod, automation, sh

One of my script is making new .sh files in /tmp/ folder how can I setup that all new files in /tmp/ folder will get chmod -x automaticaly because my script is failing when trying to run scripts in /tmp/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/311438/80864

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an entire directory executable?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546211/how-do-i-make-an-entire-directory-executable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong approach. While creating the script, set the x flag as well! Or, when executing the created script, prepend `sh` or `bash` to it:

Instead of:

```
/tmp/myscript.sh
```

use:

```
bash /tmp/myscript.sh
```

Like that you don't have to make the script executable.

Comment: What if I can't edit that file? it's very complicated script involving both .sh and .php

Comment: Than make a cron job to run: `chmod +x -R /tmp/*.sh`