# /tmp in tmpfs, how do this only with systemd?

Tags: systemd, tmp, tmpfs

I have now a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and i love it. i have mounted /tmp as tmpfs via `/etc/fstab` line as this:

```
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777    0       0
```

now, i like to know how i can do this only with `systemd`, i need only to activate a new `systemd` service only (`tmp.mount` related), or i need one more thing ? how i can replace my actual `/etc/fstab` line with `systemd` in my laptop on live mode?

Comment: If you  are a developer and use the Ubuntu to build some some os system,  "nosuid,nodev,noexec" will affect your building process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please note that using `/etc/fstab` is still the preferred approach with systemd!

See the man page for [systemd.mount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) which states:

> In general, configuring mount points through /etc/fstab is the preferred approach.

systemd ships [systemd-fstab-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html#) which converts those to mount units.

---

If you really want to turn that mount into a mount unit, my recommendation is to check its current exact configuration, with the following command:

```
$ systemctl cat tmp.mount
```

Or:

```
$ systemctl cat /tmp
```

Which will show you the dynamic unit created by systemd-fstab-generator, and should look similar to:

```
# /run/systemd/generator/tmp.mount
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=local-fs.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777
```

You could save these contents into `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount` and run `systemctl enable tmp.mount` to activate it. (You will need to add an `[Install]` section and a `WantedBy=local-fs.target` to be able to successfully enable it.)

(Another option is to use the [tmp.mount](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/tmp.mount) from the systemd sources. Some other distributions, like Fedora, are shipping and enabling that one.)

Don't forget to remove the one from `/etc/fstab`, otherwise they might conflict. (I believe the one in fstab would prevail, as I'd expect `/run` to have priority over `/etc`.)

But, as said before, managing through `/etc/fstab` is still the preferred solution... So I'd probably recommend you still stick with that one.

Comment: I have made the changes, how do I now "remount" using `systemctl` ?

Comment: You can mount a systemd mount unit with `systemctl start`, but if you had it mounted before the command you may end up with a double mount or it might fail... If you're unable to unmount it (because the filesystem is busy), perhaps rebooting is the safest way...